# Why isn't the length of my array being defined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

Apparently the length of my array "members" is undefined when i call it. I'm honestly lost on why. It says in the redux devTools theres an object in the array, so shouldn't it return the length properly? The error only occurs when i try to submit the form to show the review of the values.

```
const AddWorkout = ({ handleSubmit, submitting }) => (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        <h2>Enter Your Workout Details</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={styles.form}>
            <Field
                name="date"
                component={DatePicker}
                defaultDate={Date.now()}
                hintText="Date Of Workout"
                fullWidth={true}
                locale="en-US"
            />
            <Field
                name="name"
                component={TextField}
                floatingLabelText="Workout Name"
                style={styles.textfield}
            />
            <Field
                name="duration"
                component={TextField}
                floatingLabelText="Estimated Duration"
                style={styles.textfield}
            />
            <FieldArray name="members" component={renderExercises} />
            <div style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    color="primary"
                    variant="contained"
                    size="large"
                    disabled={submitting}
                    style={styles.button}
                >
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
);

const renderExercises = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed } }) => (
    <>
        {fields.map((exercise, idx) => {
            return (
                <div key={idx}>
                    <Field
                        fullWidth={true}
                        floatingLabelText="Exercise Name"
                        name={`${exercise}.exerciseName`}
                        component={TextField}
                    />
                    <Field
                        floatingLabelText="Starting # Of Reps"
                        type="number"
                        name={`${exercise}.reps`}
                        component={TextField}
                        style={styles.textfield}
                    />
                    <Field
                        floatingLabelText="Starting Weight"
                        type="number"
                        name={`${exercise}.weight`}
                        component={TextField}
                        style={styles.textfield}
                    />
                    <Field
                        floatingLabelText="# of Sets"
                        type="number"
                        name={`${exercise}.numberOfSets`}
                        component={TextField}
                        style={styles.textfield}
                    />
                    <Button
                        onClick={() => fields.remove(idx)}
                        size="small"
                        disableRipple
                        fullWidth
                    >
                        REMOVE EXERCISE
                    </Button>
                </div>
            );
        })}
        <Button
            type="button"
            size="small"
            disableRipple
            fullWidth
            onClick={() => fields.push({})}
        >
            Add Exercise
        </Button>
    </>
);

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'addworkout', // a unique identifier for this form
    initialValues: {
        date: new Date()
    }
    //   validate,
})(AddWorkout);
```

```
const AddWorkoutConfirm = ( values, prevStep, handleSubmit ) => {
    const { name, duration, date, members } = values;
    return (
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center", height: "100%" }}>
            <ClientMenuBar title="Confirm Your Details" />
            <h2>Enter Your Workout Details</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={styles.form}>
                <List>
                    <ListItem>Workout Name: {name}</ListItem>
                    <ListItem>Estimated Duration Of Workout: {duration} mins</ListItem>
                    <ListItem>Number Of Exercises: {members.length}</ListItem>
                    <ListItem>Date Of Workout: {date.toString()}</ListItem>
                </List>
                <div style={{ borderTop: "1px solid gray" }}>
                    {
                        members.map((exercise, index) => (
                            <List key={`${index}`}>
                                <ListItem>Exercise Name: {exercise.exerciseName}</ListItem>
                                <ListItem>Number of Sets: {exercise.numberOfSets}</ListItem>
                                <ListItem>Starting Weight: {exercise.weight} lbs</ListItem>
                                <ListItem>Starting Number Of Reps: {exercise.reps}</ListItem>
                            </List>
                        ))}
                </div>
                <br />
                <div style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
                    <Button
                        color="inherit"
                        variant="contained"
                        style={styles.button}
                        size="large"
                        onClick={prevStep}
                    >
                        Back
                </Button>
                    <Button
                        color="primary"
                        variant="contained"
                        type="submit"
                        style={styles.button}
                        size="large"
                    >
                        Confirm
                </Button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default connect(state => ({
    values: getFormValues('addworkout')(state)
}))(AddWorkoutConfirm);
```

This is the exact error it returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at AddWorkoutConfirm (AddWorkoutConfirm.jsx:21)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:13449)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:15605)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:16238)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:20279)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:20320)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19503)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:20433)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:21357)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:21267)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:21241)
    at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21526)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2268)
    at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:5085)
```

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The `AddWorkoutConfirm` component will take only a single argument called `props` - currently it is defined to take three arguments, `values`, `prevStep` and `handleSubmit`. If we remove destructuring from the argument for clarity your first few lines should be:

```
const AddWorkoutConfirm = (props) => {
  // The `values` prop comes from the first argument to your `connect` hoc 
  const { values, prevStep, handleSubmit } = props;
  const { name, duration, date, members } = values;
...
```

Of course you can move the destructuring into the component argument itself:

```
const AddWorkoutConfirm = ({ values, prevStep, handleSubmit }) => {
...
```

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean. Isn't what i did right after the line you are referencing destructuring the prop names from the props?

Comment: Ah, there are two levels of destructuring that need to happen - your `connect` function creates a `prop` called `values` that is passed down to the `AddWorkoutConfirm` component. That `values` prop is itself an object that needs to be destructured as you correctly do on the following line. But `AddWorkoutConfirm` takes only a single argument, `props`, which is an object whose keys are prop names. Right now you have `AddWorkoutConfirm` taking three arguments `(values, prevStep, handleSubmit)`.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. thx! For some reason though, that cause a different error when i changed it: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined. And again in my redux devTools, it's clearly showing that it does have the value i put in...

Comment: For that you'll have to share the code for `getFormValues` and the associated reducers since the result of `getFormValues('addworkout')(state)` is being passed as the value for the `values` prop.

Comment: getFormValues is a function of redux-form and I don't have any reducers. The state and such being passed is built in to redux-form

Comment: Ah ok, I've never used redux-form before so probably can't help much. But I would try and debug that call to `getFormValues` and make sure that it's returning what you expect.